# Angular 5 in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5

My backend is in Java and coded using Spring tool Suite. Can we Spring Tool Suite IDE for coding for Angular 5 or we require VIsual Studio Code only. If yes, can anyone help me out how to connect to angular cli using STS and in case its not possible, then how do I link my VS code to STS.
Is there any concept of ICOR / any proxy involved.

Comment: There is no Hard and Fast rule that you need only VS code for angular, you can use any IDE as per your choice

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need a Eclipse plugin, of which there are a few, all with their features and qwerks:

- https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular-ide
- https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular-eclipse

I'm sure there's more: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/angular